# Redirect page twice backward django

Tags: python, django

I am currently creating a delete method and I would like to redirect it the previous page twice

this is my code

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def delete(request):
   ...
   return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

how can I possibly let it go to previous page twice.

something like

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'), history -2)
```

Comment: HTTP_REFERER have only one currently referring so you have to fine another method... something store last previous state and redirect the usr

Comment: Relying on referrer headers to perform redirects is unreliable, dangerous and can be abused. It would be better to use sessions to remember which page a user was on and redirect based on the session history.